# I'm looking for a word/s to describe anyone elected to a position by vote

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word/s to describe anyone elected to a position by vote.

Like elector to describe the voter, or electorate for the collective, but I want to describe the person voted in to position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

> **electee**, *n.*
>
> One chosen or elected.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: omg im embarrassed.